# Can't extract data from my json response-Web Java EE Application

Tags: json, web-services, parsing

I developed a web service that extracts messages from a database and returns an object containing a table and a string, as a json response.
The problem is that I can't extract data from the client application when I consume the web service.

This is the reponse I get when I run the web service

```
{
    "msgTabl":
       {
       "list":
          [
            {"contenu":"aid  mabroukk","dateEnvoi":"2014-07-30","frommm":"voeuxmsg","id":0,"idu":0,"numExp":50840749},
            {"contenu":222222222222,"dateEnvoi":222222,"frommm":222222222222,"id":0,"idu":0,"numExp":2222222},
            {"contenu":3333333333,"dateEnvoi":3333333333,"frommm":333333333,"id":0,"idu":0,"numExp":33333333333}
          ],
        "test":"ok"
       }
}
```

I tried to take the json content from my client application, but I couldn't because of the structure of my json reponse. I don't know why this `"msgTabl"` is shown at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
reponse['msgTabl']
```

in your client application to get the right structure you want

Comment: how could i do that?
for me i consumed the ws and get the response that way :
`  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 8086, "http");
 
       HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("/TestWS/service/historiquemethod?&pseudo=" + sespseudoo + "&motDePasse=" + sesmotdepasse);


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(target, getRequest);


        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
     
   //entity respone:
       
  out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity) + " </br>");

`